# Add Split variable with single loop (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, foreach

I have a FOR EACH LOOP in VB.

It is returning the correct values in the right places, but I only want it to perform a **single** loop for Products.

```
For Each Product As String In Form1.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString.Split(", ")
 For Each Price As String In Form1.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString.Split(", ")
         Products.AppendLine(String.Format(" <tr>{0}
                                             <td>{1}</td>{0}
                                             <td align=""center"">{2}</td>{0}
                                             </tr>", Environment.NewLine,Product,Price))
 Next Price
Next Product
```

How can I add the Price variable, with out adding the additional FOR each LOOP?

I tried just adding it as a string

```
Dim Price As String = Form1.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.Split(", ")
```

However then the code errors:
'Conversion from type 'String()' to type 'String' is not valid.'

EDIT:

The cell values are:

Products (ProductA, ProductB, ProductC)
Price (£1,£2,£3)

I just want to return the product name and price, as per the row on the datagridview

Comment: Split-method does not return a string, it returns an array of strings, hence the error. Add more details in the question, we have no way of knowing what the cell values are.

Comment: Thanks Esko, cell values added

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that works with a `For Each` loop, because you want one loop that iterates over two related variables.  One way to do it would be a simple `For` loop:

```
Dim Products = Form1.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString.Split(", ")
Dim Prices = Form1.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString.Split(", ")

Debug.Assert(Products.Length = Prices.Length) 'Or provide real validation here
For i = 0 to Products.Length - 1
    Result.AppendLine(String.Format(" <tr>{0}
                                      <td>{1}</td>{0}
                                      <td align=""center"">{2}</td>{0}
                                      </tr>",
                                    Environment.NewLine,Products(i),Prices(i)))
Next
```

You could also do this using the `Zip` method from Linq:

```
Imports System.Linq

Dim Products = Form1.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString.Split(", ")
Dim Prices = Form1.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString.Split(", ")

Dim Result = Products.Zip(Prices, Function(Product, Price)
                                      String.Format(" <tr>{0}
                                                      <td>{1}</td>{0}
                                                      <td align=""center"">{2}</td>{0}
                                                      </tr>",
                                                    Environment.NewLine,Product,Price)
                                  End Function)
```

Note that as written, you may pick up extra spaces in your product and price strings.  I tried adjusting my `Split` call to make this issue go away, but in my test program, I was getting a perplexing failure to get the `Split` overload that takes an array of `String` as an argument, so I won't include that here.